# Difference in data when using core data relationships

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I'm using core data to fetch values from an sql lite database for my iphone app. I'm pretty new to the syntax so I might be missing a few key infos.

My fetch request looks like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *difficultyDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Difficulty" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[fetchRequest setEntity:difficultyDescription];
NSArray *diffResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

After that, I'm looping through the results by using this snippet:

```
systems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSManagedObject *diff in diffResults) {
 [systems addObject:diff];

 [values addObject:[diff valueForKey:@"difficultyValues"]];
}
```

What I don't get about this is, that when I log systems by using

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[systems objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

I get the result in plain text. For example "some value".

When logging the results in the "values" array however I get this result:

```
{(
    "some value"
)}
```

I'm using the same logging call:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[values objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"value"]);
```

The entities difficulty and difficultyValues have a one to many relationship.

How can I display the value in the array "values" like the one in "systems"? I need it later on for a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding. `difficultyValues` is a *relationship*, while name is an `NSString` *attribute*. That's why it appears differently in `NSLog()`, which works by sending objects a `-description` message.

The value for `difficultyValues` will be an `NSSet` which contains multiple managed objects for the entity `difficulty`.

Here's what you should do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[systems objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"name"]); // NSString*

// let's loop through all the difficulties of this item
for (NSManagedObject* aDifficulty in [[[systems objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"difficultyValues"] allObjects]) {

    NSLog(@"%@", [aDifficulty valueForKey:@"name"]);

}
```

This, of course, assuming your `difficulty` entity has a `name` attribute.